# Postfix header_checks and unicode regexp

Tags: postfix, regex, unicode

Does postfix support [unicode regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) like \p{Han} to detect unicode scripts? I would like to use them with header_checks.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for called [SMTPUTF8](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtputf8_enable). This feature is available in Postfix 3.0 and later.

You should also read [rfc6531](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6531) which specifies an SMTP extension for transport and delivery of email messages with internationalized email addresses or header information.